# render svg file and serve it using express

Tags: node.js, express, svg

I would like to know how to render and serve an svg file using Express.

Right now, I can serve an svg as a raw XML file. Here is what I am doing:

**route**

```
router.get('/status', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/status.svg'));
});
```

**svg**

```
<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke: black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
</svg>
```

When I hit that route, the raw XML of the svg file is served to the browser. How can I render it first as an SVG image, and then serve it?

Comment: You don't render it first, the browser renders it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify your SVG file into this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke: black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: To explain: These (xmlns) attributes define namespaces and the browser needs these to recognise that the markup is SVG, and not some other svg element from some other specification as unlikely as that might be.

Answer (score 4):

If by "render" you assume the question asks how to create and serve a *dynamically generated* SVG then your code could work like this:

```js
let svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="400">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">${String(Math.random())}</text>
</svg>`;

router.get("/render-svg", (req, res, next) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
      'Content-Length': svg.length
    });
    res.end(svg);
});
```